# How do I extract all numbers at the end of a line that ends with "#.#ms"?

Tags: regex

I'm trying to analyze some log files. Each line looks something like this:

```
2015-06-03 16:09:05,615 200 GET /url/endpoint (127.0.0.1) 19.15ms
2015-06-03 16:09:06,615 200 GET /url/endpoint (127.0.0.1) 2.19ms
```

I've found that if the 'ms' wasn't there I could do something like this to get the last one

```
\d*\.?\d*$
```

But even that would only get the last timestamp.

Any thoughts or hints are greatly appreciated!

Comment: what regex flavor are you using?

Comment: What is the text when there is no decimal value? One of `19.0ms`, `19.ms` or `19ms`?

Comment: Sorry, but I'm actually not sure (way too many entries and too rare of a case for me to find by perusing the file)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `ms` part is easy, because it is matched verbatim: if you want it matched at the end of the string, simply put it at the end of your regex.

If each line is terminated by `\n`, you could use it in your regex:

```
\d+\.\d{2}ms\n
```

[demo1.](https://regex101.com/r/tG3bV6/1)

Depending on your system, you could match end-of-line with `$` by specifying a multi-line option. The way you do this is dependent on the system that provides your regex implementation ([demo2](https://regex101.com/r/aI4iY5/2)).

Answer (score 1):

Easily you can use grouping to catch only the numbers

```
(\d+\.\d+)ms$
```

Then, use the group reference `\1` to get only numbers.

More here: [POSIX Basic Regular Expressions](http://www.regular-expressions.info/posix.html)

Answer (score 1):

A simple approach (with basic POSIX regexes):

```
[[:space:]]\(.*\)ms$
```

A space followed by the time and `ms` after it - at the end of the line. The result is in capturing group 1.

Answer (score 0):

You can probably just use `(\d+|\d+\.\d+)ms` to get the number, since there is no other "ms" on the lines. If you want to use "$" at the end of lines you should set your regex flavor to be multiline.

If you are using POSIX regexes, you might need to use `\(` and `\)` instead of `(` and `)`.

Like this: https://regex101.com/r/jN8eP6/1.